# APACHE CAMEL : error/exception handling in file Producer

Tags: apache-camel

In Camel in Action book, it is written that default exception handling is for the life span of exchange object only. Suppose I am using following route -

```
from(sftp:{details}).to(file:{details})
```

1st query -> For the above route, I think the consumer is sftp and the producer is file. Am I right here?

2nd query -> How can we handle the exception at destination end point (which is outside the life span of exchange object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st** You are correct.

**2nd** Any exception that will be raised before the file is successfully written to disk will trigger Camel's exception handling which will by default in file based components trigger rollback of the original file so that data won't be lost.

Comment: Thanks jnupponen, for the prompt response. What will happen, after the roll back. If i am using onException block, will i be able to get the exception on the attached processor?

Comment: When you create your consumer like that with sftp it will become Polling Consumer. After the rollback it just tries again at the time that is specified for the Polling Consumer (e.g. delay=60s). You can get the exception in the onException processor, see [here](http://camel.apache.org/why-is-the-exception-null-when-i-use-onexception.html). Heads up with the exception handlers, though: you can easily mess your files if you handle the exception which results in that rollback is not being called.

Comment: That is the case of consumer and you explained the concept of producer too in your first comment. My concern is related to producer end point. Suppose at the time of writing the file in producer we got some exception. So, according to you file will be rolled back. Will the context retry this operation? And another question is ... Can we catch the exception raised from file producer